# page redirection not working in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

After deleting the record, the page should be redirected.This is my code:

```
 <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" id="btnAssetDelete">
      <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Patent__c.Delete, objAsset.id,[retURL='/apex/AssetDetails'])}" onclick="return window.confirm('Are you sure?');">
          Delete
      </apex:outputLink>
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `apex:commandLink` instead of `apex:outputLink` as follows:

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" id="btnAssetDelete">
      <apex:commandLink action="{!URLFOR($Action.Patent__c.Delete, objAsset.id,[retURL='/apex/AssetDetails'])}" onclick="return window.confirm('Are you sure?');">
          Delete
      </apex:commandLink>
 </button>
```

Comment: even though it is not redirecting

Comment: do you have controller method? Is so then you can redirect from controller

Comment: or you can use `oncomplete` function for redirection

Comment: yes ,is there.i tried not redirecting